# Inserting values from two tables into a new table

Tags: mysql

I ran this query:

```
Insert into transaction(matric,surname,other,level,bk_id,bk_title) 
values(
   (select matric,surname,others,level from member_master),
   (select isbn,bk_title from book_master)
)
```

but I got this error:

> column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking. The error message you refer to seems to be quite obvious. The column count of the database table does not match the column count in your statement. If this is not the case, please explain.

Comment: show us your database diagram. how do you want tables be assigned to each other?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same columns which you have mentioned in the `insert` statement. Presently your `insert` statement mentions `matric,surname,other,level,bk_id,bk_title` columns whereas the columns in `select` are different. Try like this:

```
Insert into transaction(matric,surname,other,level,bk_id,bk_title) 
values
(select m.matric,m.surname,m.others,m.level,b.isbn,b.bk_title
 from member_master m inner join book_master b on m.id = b.id)
```

Assuming that the two tables are linked with the ID column